# the camera preview does not appear when I print the label

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I share the code below when I turn on the camera, I print the label and the label does not appear. What is the problem?

but the label does not appear and it does not appear in my program My program detects the object and I need to print it with the label at the end but unfortunately I can not print the label

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo

    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)  else{ return }

    guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }

    captureSession.addInput(input)
    captureSession.startRunning()

    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame

    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "CameraQueue"))
    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
}

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else { return }
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model : model) {(finishedReq,error) in
        guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else{ return }

        guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
        print(firstObservation.identifier , firstObservation.confidence)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.label.text = "\(firstObservation.identifier) ,\(firstObservation.confidence)"
        }   
    }

    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.label)` after you add the preview layer to the view's subview. When you add the preview layer, it will be on top of the existing subviews.

Comment: Just to confirm, is your label a direct subview of self.view, or is it a subview of a different view?

Comment: direct bottom view

Comment: I suggest debugging with the View Hierarchy Tool - you can get a 3D view to see what is blocking the label, and proceed from there: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html